Надо ли закрывать конструкции с союзом А?
Например:
А то я когда-то в чате что-то читал об этом, возможно, и так не полный вариант, а скорее какие-то обсуждения для знающих(,) и поэтому плохо понимаю, как там на самом деле дело было.
То есть интересует и этот случай и вообще общее правило для закрытия конструкций, начинающихся с А. Sharon, жду вас с нетерпением! :)
21 декабря 2024
Исправил "придаточные" на "конструкции", сначала их ошибочно назвал придаточными (те, кто ставили запятые в конце их, ввели меня в заблуждение и я их стал таковыми считать).

Основное правило по теме: Розенталь § 12. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами, пункт 5 и 6
  5. Между однородными членами предложения, 
  соединенными посредством противительных союзов а, 
  но, да (в значении ‘но’)… ставится запятая: 
  Теперь море сияло уже не сплошь, а лишь в 
  нескольких местах (Кат.)…
  6. После последнего однородного члена 
  предложения, присоединяемого противительным или 
  подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой 
  предложения, запятая не ставится (т. е. последний 
  однородный член не обособляется): Не род, а ум 
  поставлю в воеводы (П.); Каждый вечер солнце 
  садилось в море, а не в тучи и было при этом 
  клюквенного цвета (Ю. К.)… 


Сначала в качестве варианта рассмотрим обособление пояснительной конструкции двумя тире:

А то я когда-то в чате что-то читал об этом — возможно, и так не полный вариант, а скорее какие-то обсуждения для знающих — и поэтому плохо понимаю, как там на самом деле дело было.
Использовано правило:  Розенталь § 19. Обособленные приложения
  10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой 
  употребляется тире:   3) для выделения (с двух сторон) 
  приложения, носящего характер пояснения: Какая-то 
  ненатуральная зелень — творение скучных беспрерывных 
  дождей — покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы (Г.); 

Исходное предложение: А то я когда-то в чате что-то читал об этом и поэтому плохо понимаю, как там на самом деле дело было.

Рассмотрим пояснительную конструкцию с союзом А: возможно, и так не полный вариант, а скорее какие-то обсуждения для знающих.

Здесь использовано противопоставление вида НЕ...А.  Отношения однородные (не вариант, а обсуждения), поэтому ставится одна запятая.

А теперь можно оставить обособление двумя тире или заменить запятыми:

А то я когда-то в чате что-то читал об этом, возможно, и так не полный вариант, а скорее какие-то обсуждения для знающих, и поэтому плохо понимаю, как там на самом деле дело было.
ВЫВОД
Итак, в данном предложении союз А используется для построения оборота с противопоставлением, но вообще об этом союзе можно целый рассказ написать. Он действительно удивительный и заслуживает отдельной темы. Поэтому задайте вопрос или я могу сама открыть тему, это на ваше усмотрение.

Спасибо! Значит, после "знающих" нужна всё-таки запятая? А чем она обосновывается?

Да, нужна, но это не связано с союзом А. Обособляется пояснительная конструкция. Сравнить:  А то я читал не полный вариант, а скорее какие-то обсуждения и поэтому плохо понимаю, как там на самом деле дело было. // Здесь нет запятой.

А в конструкции "не... а" ставят две запятых: перед А и в конце оборота?

Запятой в конце оборота нет: Я читал не полный вариант, а обсуждения и плохо понял.  Здесь однородные отношения между дополнениями, нет уточнения.  А почему вы хотели бы поставить запятую?

Да нет, я не хотел бы, я не знал, надо или не надо. Вот хотелось поподробнее об этом в ответе. Про обычный случай, когда нет пояснительной конструкции. Не только мой пример чтобы разобрали, но и другие такие случаи. Ой, я, оказывается, забыл плюсик поставить, исправился! :)

Артем, своим вопросом я  приглашаю вас поучаствовать в конференции на тему: "Что необычного в этом союзе, почему он требует к себе постоянного внимания?".  Почему вам кажется, что там может быть обособление? В вашем примере союз А  – законопослушный сочинительный союз при однородных членах,  поэтому нет обособления.  Но во многих темах он любит соединяться с разными  словами (вводные слова, деепричастия и т. д.).  Как вы думаете, что в нем особенного? Если я буду о нем рассказывать, то желательно послушать разные мнения.

А то я часто на форуме говорю с пустым залом – меня даже упрекают: кому нужны ваши вопросы-ответы? Прямо вот таким текстом) С другой стороны,  к нам разные люди заходят, может, кому-то нужны.

Возможно, Sharon, необычного ничего, я просто считал такие предложения придаточными, а они не такие, видимо, да? Как в вашем примере: Я читал не полный вариант...

Да, я вижу по названию вопроса... Но ведь в придаточном должен быть подчинительный союз, а здесь его нет,  да и связь явно сочинительная, а не подчинительная. Но все равно спасибо за вопрос, я по нему нашла очень интересные сведения о сюзе А, чего раньше не знала. Поэтому голос от меня)

Спасибо большое, Шарон! Возможно, я видел, что другие ставят эту ненужную запятую часто, вот и не мог понять, надо на самом деле или нет.
